# Fatal error: Uncaught Error while entering the dashboard and in some shop pages

Tags: wordpress, syntax-error

recently my WordPress website https://authouse.ir/ faced  an error

**Fatal error**: Uncaught Error: Value of type null is not callable in /home/sywwqmum/public_html/wp-includes/load.php:1 Stack trace: #0 /home/sywwqmum/public_html/wp-settings.php(35): require() #1 /home/sywwqmum/public_html/wp-config.php(96): require_once('/home/sywwqmum/...') #2 /home/sywwqmum/public_html/wp-load.php(50): require_once('/home/sywwqmum/...') #3 /home/sywwqmum/public_html/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('/home/sywwqmum/...') #4 /home/sywwqmum/public_html/index.php(17): require('/home/sywwqmum/...') #5 {main} thrown in **/home/sywwqmum/public_html/wp-includes/load.php** on line **1**

on **some pages** like :

https://authouse.ir/product-category/irrigation-package/page/2/

when I refresh the page by URL the error is hidden.. but from the woocomerce button, it can't find the page..

furthermore, while entering the dashboard even by **authouse.ir/wp-login.php**  this error is shown.

I'm wondering if u can help me...

I deactivated all plugins by the way of the host server..also  I improved the PHP version

all did not work....

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To help us finding the bug you will need to add the PHP file/files to the question and limit them to the smallest possible content that is sufficient to demonstrate the issue

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.... Sure.. How I can share files?

Comment: The regular case would be to add all relevant code directly to the question. See here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402268/how-can-i-insert-a-php-code-snippet-in-markdown-of-stack-overflow for ideas how to do this with PHP code. And this for general advice about creating a minimal example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It might become a bit awkward in your case. My suggestion is to start with load.php and a minimal version of the html site that throws this error.

Comment: ok...Thank u ...I'll test it...

Comment: It might be helpful if you go back to a previous development stage where everyrhing worked smoothly - then add the recent new features one by one and observe which change breaks the design (I'm not experienced in web design but I think it's a general good advice to work step by step, supported by a version control system).

Comment: The problem is I don't know when this error happened .. and the backup version is like this, I mean, the ruined version is overwritten.. otherwise, I could restore it..thank u for ur reply

Comment: I have visited your site just a minute ago and back at Sep 26, and did not notice any error. Is there any action required on my behalf to trigger it? Maybe it's coming from your development environment. I'm ready to help if required.

Comment: Thank u for all ur suggestions, I replaced Wordpress files with new ones except wp-content and wp-config-sample...  and the problem was solved... ;)

Comment: Nice to read this. The site looks great. I was missing an EN button for international customers, and some dialogs use mixed language, but it's great. I'm here if you need more help.

Comment: Thank you for ur warm words  :)   ,  You made me eager to make my site bilingual.... Wish u the best...